# always display first and last values when using tick amount in apex chart

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

[image]

```
<template>
 
    <apexchart width="800" type="line" :options="chartOptions" :series="series">
    </apexchart>
  </div>


<script setup lang="ts">

let chartOptions = reactive({
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'line',
    zoom: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },

  xaxis: {
    type: 'numeric',
    tickPlacement: 'between',
    tickAmount: 3,
    overwriteCategories: [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'oct',
      'nov',
      'dec',
    ],
  },
});

const series = reactive([
  {
    name: 'Desktops',
    data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 148],
  },
]);
</script>
```

I am using apexcharts and as you can see in above chart the last element is not visible.
Is there a way to use tickAmount in a way that last element and the first doesnt get cut off?

Also tick value when set to 3 is giving 4 poi ts instead.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I was able to make it work is with this

```
xaxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      labels: {
        rotate: -45,
        rotateAlways: true,
        showDuplicates: true,
        format: 'DD-MMM-YY',
        formatter: function (value, dateObj) {
          return dayjs(dateObj).format('DD MMM YY') // YOu can use moment and/or any format
        },
      }
    },
```